# An Extension of Linearization

Tags: calculus

I'm not sure where to even begin with this...

Let $f(x) = \sin x$. The polynomial $p(x)= Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx +D$ is a function such that $p^{k} (0) = f^{k} (0)$ for $k=0,1,2,3$

a) Determine $p(x)$ by computing the values of $A,B,C$ and $D$

Comment: You can start by plugging in $ x=0$ to figure out what $ D $ is.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by setting up the equations as follows:
$$p(0)=f(0)$$
$$p'(0)=f'(0)$$
$$p''(0)=f''(0)$$
$$p'''(0)=f'''(0)$$
then find the necessary derivatives of $p$ and $f$. Note that there are four equations and four variables to solve for ($A,B,C,D$)